# Add a custom TLS extension on Android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, jsse, boringssl

I am developing an Android application and want to add a custom extension on the TLS/SSL ClientHello handshake. Both OpenSSL and BoringSSL support the necessary functionality and callbacks to add custom extensions, but unfortunately Android JSSE providers don't seem to expose this functionality.

I believe I have at least two choices:

1. One way would be to modify conscrypt, add support for custom extensions, and bundle the libraries (native .so + .jar) in my app.
2. Find another JSEE provider that either supports custom extensions, or it's easier than conscrypt to modify and bundle.

Rgearding (1), I couldn't find any good instructions on how to bundle conscrypt with a specific app, and a first attempt to build against source and manually add the libraries in my app doesn't work (I can't import anything from conscrypt). It is also very likely to have class conflicts even if this gets resolved.

What would be the best way to add support for my application?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way to add a custom TLS extension on Android?